# What is the most efficent way to allow users to bookmark pages (ids, nodes, etc) with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My website has a few thousand events, simple PHP pages driven by a mysql database.

I want to allow my users to "bookmark" or "save" or "favorite" events that look interesting to them.  Probably just a simple AJAX toggle that will take that event "ID" field from mysql and add it to their list.

What is the best way to go about this without killing my DB?  My concern is that when users are browsing a list of events on my website, I need to show a small icon next to the event title that is either already marked as "saved" or not.  I'm afraid if I dont do it correctly I will just be hammering my DB 25 times on each page load.

Any insight into this issue?

EDIT: Also, what is the best way to store the list of ID's a user has saved in mysql?  Create a new table?  Can I throw them in a field in the existing users table?

Comment: use AJAX to save/update the bookmarks but update your page load/display logic to show the saved bookmarks every time the page loads. I think this should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first query what are the **user's favorite items**, and then when rendering the table of items, check against this list if the item is favorited or not.

That way, it's all done in just two queries.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
$user_favorite_ids = getUserFavoriteItems(); // array of IDs

$page_entries = getPageEntries(); // array of objects (DB rows)

foreach(page_entries as $entry) {

   // print table row

   if(in_array($entry->id, $user_favorite_ids)) {
       // show as "favorite"
   }
}
```

---

This will, however, not be very efficient if your user has hundreds or thousands of favourite items.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking I will auto delete items from a users favorite list a week or so after the event date has past, which should keep these lists fairly small.

Comment: What would be the best way to store that users list of favorites?  At first I was thinking I would just put a list into a field in the users table, but if I deleted a node, say "35" it would be impossible to easily remove that ID from everyones list unless it is easily accessible in the db -- any ideas?

Comment: You can have a table: `user_bookmarks` : (bookmark_id, user_id, some_other_stuff ... ) - bookmark_id being an auto-increment primary key - then it's all in one big table, and you can easily query bookmarks per user, just as well as delete individual bookmarks. You can also make a "creationDate" column there, if you want to do some auto-erasing of old stuff.